# python как разделить текст

Tags: python, python-3.x

у меня есть такой код:

```
print("Hello world")
```

как разделите текст чтобы вместо hello world писалось world

Comment: почитать первый попавшийся учебник.

Comment: print("world").

Comment: @КириллМалышев можно как-то подругому мне нужно именно разделить а не писать просто текст

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте встроенный метод для строк [str.split(sep=None, maxsplit=-1)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
a = "Hello world"
b = a.split()
```

Теперь в b у вас список из слов:

```
>>> b 
["Hello", "world"]
```

Выводите на печать элемент с нужным индексом:

```
>>> print(b[1])
world
```

Comment: Ну и как? помогли гражданину? думаете, он по ссылке прошёл, почитал?

Comment: @strawdog надеюсь, что да, я верю в лучшие человеческие качества